# Using stylecop to set boolean variable rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

A boolean variable must have a prefix is, such as: `bool isFinished;`
How can I write a custom rule for it? (I'm using stylecop)

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good rule. You can have a binary state machine where prefixing the state name with "is" isn't appropriate.

Comment: I agree, and I doubt that it would ever become part of the official StyleCop codebase, but it might be entirely appropriate for their situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [Custom StyleCop Rule](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Create%20StyleCop%20Custom%20Rule).  You would basically create another .dll which you can then drop into your StyleCop directory.  This way you can create custom rules that make sense to your team and still take advantage of StyleCop's future releases.

Comment: I know that, but I do not know how to check is a var is boolean or not.
I look for something like:

`if (returntype == bool && elementType != method) checkstartwith'is';`

But I don't know what exactly what the code is

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

- Download the SDK from the [StyleCop Downloads page](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/79972).
- Review the details of [how to set up your environment to build StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SetUpDevBox&referringTitle=Documentation).

A good starting point would be to copy and modify one of the [existing rules](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/Naming%20Rules.html).